# Apply a function to a specific column for every row in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to apply a user defined function to a specific column for every row in a dataframe in R and save the result back into the column.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After nearly 3 hours of reading Stack Overflow answers about slightly different use cases and playing around with apply, lapply, sapply etc. here's the code that allows you to do this:

```
your_function <- function(x) {
    if(x == 3) {
        x = 333
    } else {
        x = 1
    }
}

df$colname <- sapply(df$colname, your_function)
```

Comment: Did you know the answer before asking it?

Comment: Why question and answer both are posted in the same time? If you know the answer than what is the reason for posting the question?

Comment: Well, seeing as I couldn't find the answer to my question elsewhere. I figured perhaps posting what I found might help someone else with the same question. There's actually a checkbox you can check to answer your own question.

Comment: Yeah, it's explicitly encouraged: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer Thanks for sharing @stroz - it helped me